# IoT Dashboard for customers (data comes from Arduino)

Tags: esp8266, arduino, esp32, aws-iot, azure

I push my sensor readings from product A, B, C, D to an online cloud provider.
Then my customer (call him E) needs to access **all** these sensor readings and make a dashboard for his customer X, Y Z.

Customer X needs to login and then see only product readings A and B
Customer Y needs to login and then see only product readings C
Customer Z needs to login and then see only product readings D.

My customer E needs to make

- a login for his clients X, Y, Z
- assign and design a dashboards with the correct products coupled to his customer

Anyone any idea what suits the bests?
I am currently looking at https://thingsboard.io/ but they have a (too) high pricing scheme for this project. Also looking about google and microsoft azure, but not sure if they have the option to create and design dashboards for customers X, Y, Z.

edit

The system scale is very small. Maximum of 100 device will come online. The only thing they will show is the remaining amount of liquid and if it is in operational state.

The customers will be maximum of 25 total.

I prefer to have something in the cloud as then i would not have to do the maintenance of the server / updates.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  How much coding are you willing to do yourself?  How many different networks are these devices all distributed over?  And how expandable do you want the system to be?  What I mean is, if this is all you want, it would not be difficult at all to whip up a website with this kind of capacity...  On the other hand if you're wanting to make a central hub with multiple clients E, it might require a bit more.  It would be awesome of you could [edit] in a bit more detail on what you're looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would look at [Node Red](http://nodered.org) for an IoT dashboard.  (Indeed, http://remuda.omnipresense.com/ui is my dashboard for speeds on my street, and done using Node Red on a Raspberry Pi)   The almost-built-in Dashboard module is pretty powerful for making interfaces.  The dashboard widgets are zero-code drag-and-drop widgets that typically look great.

The complexity you specify (some customers getting different views) is not supported by the stock Node Red Dashboard.  There are multiple ways to solve this:

A) one Node Red server per desired dashboard (and somehow pushing the data to each Node Red that needs this data.  Perhaps by a unifying Node Red, or perhaps by the sensor or perhaps the receiver (is it an MQTT broker?) of the sensor data.

By the way, there are multiple Node Red hosting companies.  Alternatively, you can host it in the cloud yourself.  Good instructions are [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-your-internet-of-things-with-node-red-on-ubuntu-16-04).  Google is your friend and Node Red is widely used.

B) There is a Node Red plugin called node-red-contrib-mdashboard which describes itself as
A fork of node-red-dashboard project that lets multiple users input data without updating other screens.  That may preserve the drag-and-drop method of configuring with dashboard nodes.

C) A different plugin, node-red-contrib-uibuilder, allows more of a roll-your-own interface.

I don't know your data cloud location or transport, your skill with coding, E's skill with coding, or X, Y and Z's requirements, so my advice would be to go with option A (a Node Red as traffic cop, one Node Red per dashboard) and whip it out quickly until you feel comfortable with the complexities of Options B and C.

Comment: Pretty cool, what sensor are you using to measure the speeds on your street?